# strpos not working as expected, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, strpos

I was attempting to follow the [example on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for strpos() but it does not seem to be working as expected for me.  It keeps printing the else case "not here".

```
$href = "[!--\$testUrl('testlink','754')--]";
dpm($href);
$search_wcm = 'testUrl';
$pos_wcm = strpos($search_wcm, $href);
if ($pos_wcm !== false) {
  dpm('here');
} else {
  dpm('not here');
}
```

Note: dpm is a Drupal function that simply displays information in the messages region of a Drupal site.  Think of it as an 'echo' or 'print' with styling attached to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong order, the first param should be the string to search in

```
$pos_wcm = strpos($href, $search_wcm);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the manual you have your arguments backwards:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

> `mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`

```
strpos($href,$search_wcm)
```